# Toggle div to expand semantic ui card component

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I'm using the [`<Card>`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/views/card/) component from Semantic-UI-React. I have a group of cards displaying some random information. I have the `extra` prop defined which renders a button. My idea is to have this button, when clicked, toggle/expand a div to display more information. I have looked around and not been able to find much on how to achieve this.

I looked into [`<Accordion>`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/accordion/) from semantic ui as well, but have not been able to get it to play nicely nested inside the card component.

I [created a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-hodgkin-oq1dx) to show what I have so far and the general look of what I explained above.

For brevity I will only post the code of one card out of the group below.

```
 <Card color="blue">
     <Card.Content header="Elliot" textAlign="center" />
     <Card.Content description="'Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat.'" />
     <Card.Content extra>
       <Button basic circular icon size="tiny">
       <Icon name="plus circle" />
       </Button>
       Show More
     </Card.Content>
 </Card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @brandon-r that you can handle the extra content being show by handling a state object (in my case an array). What I did differently from his example was to take advantage of the `<Card.Content extra>` component, which handles all the styles issues.

To handle opening and closing the extra content, I used a simple reducer. I like to use the `useReducer` hook on those UI interactions that need a more complex state handling. Then I created three components: one that shows the extra content when opened, another that shows the button to display the content, and a third one that toggles between the two. I did it this way to be able to generalise it in the future.

Anyways, here is the link to my forked CodeSandbox with my take on the solution:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/semantic-ui-card-extra-content-toggle-kybt2

[image]

I hope it helps

---

**Edit #1**
Added `style={{height: "100%"}}` to the card so they mantain their size when one of the cards is opened.

**Edit #2**
Add picture showing a card with a long description.

```
<Card color="blue" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
  <Card.Content header="Elliot" textAlign="center" />
  <Card.Content description="'Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat.'" />
  <ExtraContentAccordion
    content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ac commodo diam, et tincidunt massa. Sed aliquet tortor purus, in pulvinar enim mattis ac. Maecenas vestibulum cursus lorem, quis fermentum enim lacinia a. Ut nec feugiat nisl. Morbi finibus hendrerit diam, id iaculis nibh feugiat sed. Sed non justo turpis. Fusce neque quam, facilisis eu aliquam vitae, hendrerit nec nulla. Integer metus sapien, dictum eget viverra et, dictum in lectus. Integer vitae dolor ut libero dictum tristique eget non nunc. Suspendisse diam urna, pretium sed elementum sed, fermentum eu leo. Donec augue tortor, rhoncus id pulvinar ac, fringilla eu est. Duis et ante tristique dui molestie maximus at ut enim. Curabitur facilisis tempor lorem quis scelerisque. Maecenas enim leo, mollis at egestas in, vulputate eget risus."
    onToggle={toggleCard(1)}
    open={state[1]}
  />
</Card>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I like the use of the `extra` prop here. I do have the same thought on your implementation too. When you expand one card it also adds height to the other cards in the row without actually expanding them.

Comment: @DJ2, I have updated the example to fix that. What was missing was setting the height of the cards to `100%`.

Comment: You may have not saved it. Anyway, i tried applying `style={{  height: 100% }}` to the `<Card>` component and I"m still having issues with them expanding the whole rows

Comment: Now its done. I forgot to save the last changes. Basically, I added `style={{ height: "100%"}}` to the cards component. Check the sandbox again and it should be working. It looks like this: https://imgur.com/a4ykIgU

Comment: If I double or triple the `description` text inside `<Card.Content description / >` it also throws off alignment as well

Comment: @DJ2, I can't reproduce what you said. I've updated the example so that the second card has a very long text and everything works fine. Please check the image and codesandbox demo to see what I mean.

Comment: I very much appreciate the additional fixes for the solution. Cheers

Comment: No problem. Glad to help

Comment: regarding my last issue about `description` size, here's a sandbox reproducing the issue I was talking about. Is there a way to set the height of the cards so they are all as big as the biggest one? https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-card-extra-content-toggle-8ysz6

Comment: This comment section and question is getting pretty long. You should open a new question for this issue. On that post, you can reference this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expand to show more content, you can keep track of which cards are expanded with some react state. In the UI, you can use the state to determine if you should render the extra content for a particular card.

EX:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Card, Button, Icon } from "semantic-ui-react";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState({});
  const cards = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Card.Group itemsPerRow={3}>
        {cards.map(cardNumber => (
          <Card color="blue">
            <Card.Content header="Elliot" textAlign="center" />
            <Card.Content description="'Elliot is a sound engineer living in Nashville who enjoys playing guitar and hanging with his cat.'" />
            <Card.Content extra>
              <Button
                basic
                circular
                icon
                size="tiny"
                onClick={() =>
                  setExpanded({
                    ...expanded,
                    [cardNumber]: !expanded[cardNumber]
                  })
                }
              >
                <Icon name="plus circle" />
              </Button>
              {expanded[cardNumber] && (
                <div style={{ height: 200 }}>
                  Extra content expanded for card {cardNumber}
                </div>
              )}
              Show More
            </Card.Content>
          </Card>
        ))}
      </Card.Group>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is a short sandbox to see what it looks like: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-mayer-t12ot

Comment: Nice example. Although if you expand a card in one row all the other cards expand as well without actually being expanded via the `onClick`. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: The reason all the cards in the row expand is because it is in the `Card.Group` (the group makes the row the same height). If you don't want them to be the same height, you can remove `Card.Group` but you will need to position them on your own. I updated my example to show what I mean: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-mayer-t12ot

Comment: using your first example all I had to do was set  `height: 100%` like @guzmonne said above `<Card style={{ height: "100%" }} color="blue">`. That made so the only card that expanded was in fact the one you clicked.

Comment: @DJ2 Nice, I didn't realize that. Thanks for the follow up